Ошибка при попытке записи в словарь пары ключ-значение
Пытаюсь немного модифицировать учебный пример с решением задачи коммивояжёра, так чтобы код сортировал сумму цен по возрастанию. Для этого я создал статическое поле со словарем <int, string>, в качестве ключа планировал использовать общую цену объезда всех городов, а в качестве значения - перечень этих городов.
До момента добавления новой пары в словарь всё работает правильно, но при добавлении выскакивает ошибка:
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
Ранее использовать в поле словарь мне не приходилось, подозреваю, что ошибка совсем детская и легко исправимая, но не знаю в чём она. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Благодарю, помогло!
